# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity when calling Rails from Android

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" when I try to use my android app to call the create action on one of the controllers in my rails service.  Also says "Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity" after that.  Any ideas what would cause that?  Thanks.

Comment: Plesse show your api controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the built-in CSRF protection Rails uses by default by adding in your controller (ApplicationController or the one being used) the [`protect_from_forgery`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) method:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Or also by using the `skip_before_action` to "skip" the `verify_authenticity_token` implementation.

Comment: But there must be for sure a way to update via android app while keeping CSRF protection on.